# ¿Cómo hacer que el ícono de eliminar no cambie al ícono de agregar cuando recargo la página en LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Tengo dos íconos, uno para agregar y otro para eliminar

```js
function FavId() {
   // localStorage.setItem("favn1", "<a href='/details/title'><img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659560893497-bb094425bd21?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1498&q=80'></a>");
    boton_add = document.getElementById("add");
    boton_add.style.display = "none";
    
    boton_remove = document.getElementById("remove");
    boton_remove.style.display = "block";
  }

  function Removefav() {
   // localStorage.removeItem("favn1");
    
    boton_remove = document.getElementById("remove");
    boton_remove.style.display = "none";
  
    boton_add = document.getElementById("add");
    boton_add.style.display = "block";
  }
```

```css
body {
        background-color: black;
      }

      i {
        font-size: 50px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #remove {
        display: none;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-regular-rounded/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-solid-rounded/css/uicons-solid-rounded.css'>
    <title>Fav 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <i onclick="FavId()" class="fi fi-rr-add" id="add"></i>
  <i onclick="Removefav()" class="fi fi-sr-cross-circle" id="remove"></i>


</body>
</html>
```

, como saben el ícono agregar es el ícono predeterminado al iniciar la página, básicamente lo que quiero es que cuando haga clic en el ícono "agregar" se convierta en "eliminar", pero eso el ícono de eliminar está allí cuando vuelve a cargar o cierra la página, a menos que haga clic en eliminar (entonces sería el ícono de agregar).

aquí un ejemplo de lo que quiero. [image: VER IMAGEN]

PD: no quiero utilizar cookies para esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer lo que pretendes deberás usar un valor persistente entre sesiones. Ya que no quieres usar cookies, la opción, creo que más lógica, es usar el almacenamiento local

Modifica tus funciones para que almacenen el estado actual de forma local

```
    function FavId() {
        // localStorage.setItem("favn1", "<a href='/details/title'><img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659560893497-bb094425bd21?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1498&q=80'></a>");
        boton_add = document.getElementById("add");
        boton_add.style.display = "none";
        
        boton_remove = document.getElementById("remove");
        boton_remove.style.display = "block";
        localStorage.setItem('estado', 'eliminar');  // <=== Añade esto
    }

    function Removefav() {
        // localStorage.removeItem("favn1");
        
        boton_remove = document.getElementById("remove");
        boton_remove.style.display = "none";
      
        boton_add = document.getElementById("add");
        boton_add.style.display = "block";
        localStorage.setItem('estado', 'agregar'); // <=== Añade esto
    }

    /*
    Añade esta función
    */
    function CheckEstado(){
        const estado = localStorage.getItem('estado');
        if(estado == 'eliminar')
          FavId();
        else
          Removefav();
    }
```

Y en el HTML llama a la función CheckEstado al cargarse la página, por ejemplo

```
<body>
    <i onclick="FavId()" class="fi fi-rr-add" id="add"></i>
    <i onclick="Removefav()" class="fi fi-sr-cross-circle" id="remove"></i>
<!—AÑADE ESTO -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    CheckEstado();
    </script>

</body>
```

Básicamente lo que hace es que cada vez que cambias el estado del botón, este se almacena en el localStorage. Cuando se carga la página, se lee el estado desde el localStorage y en función de su valor se activa un botón u otro llamando a la función correspondiente.

Comment: me funcionó perfectamente, muchas gracias